# How We can receive event from Azure event hub without Storage Container Name ,StorageAccountName and StorageAccountKey these information

Tags: c#, azure, azure-eventhub

I am new to Azure platform,  I have only EventHubConnectionString and EventHubName and I don't have Storage Container Name, StorageAccountName and storage account key.
I want to develop one application which receives events from event hub but I am confused about how should I proceed wihtout this information.Please help with this problem.

I am following this link for reference [Azure Event Hub.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-dotnet-framework-getstarted-receive-eph)

Comment: Storage account name and key are under the "Access Keys" tab of your Storage Account instance in the azure portal.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about locating values in Azure's web portal, not programming.

Comment: The question is very relevant and not off-topic in my opinion.  I believe the question is *how can I write a consumer of Azure Event Hub events without using Azure Storage*.

Answer (score 2):

> I am confused about how should I proceed wihtout this information

It seems that in order to use Event Hub, you are required to have something to manage checkpoints.  Most of the examples and documentation show using Azure Storage to hold the checkpoints that are automatically made by the current .Net Azure SDK code base.  The current documentation on the [EventProcessorHost](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.eventprocessorhost?view=azure-dotnet) doesn't appear to show the one of the constructors that does not require a storage account but a custom class that you write that derives from [ICheckpointManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.icheckpointmanager?view=azure-dotnet).

The constructor that isn't documented (at this point in time) looks like:

```
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Create a new host to process events from an Event Hub.
    //     This overload of the constructor allows maximum flexibility. This one allows
    //     the caller to specify the name of the processor host as well. The overload also
    //     allows the caller to provide their own lease and checkpoint managers to replace
    //     the built-in ones based on Azure Storage.
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   hostName:
    //     Name of the processor host. MUST BE UNIQUE. Strongly recommend including a Guid
    //     to ensure uniqueness.
    //
    //   eventHubPath:
    //     The name of the EventHub.
    //
    //   consumerGroupName:
    //     The name of the consumer group within the Event Hub.
    //
    //   eventHubConnectionString:
    //     Connection string for the Event Hub to receive from.
    //
    //   checkpointManager:
    //     Object implementing ICheckpointManager which handles partition checkpointing.
    //
    //   leaseManager:
    //     Object implementing ILeaseManager which handles leases for partitions.
    public EventProcessorHost(string hostName, string eventHubPath, string consumerGroupName, string eventHubConnectionString, ICheckpointManager checkpointManager, ILeaseManager leaseManager);
```

Comment: thanks, Erik  for this information, as I am new to this platform as well as for C# also I am not able to how  to make a connection to Azure Event hub for receiving the message without storage information .It would be great help for me if you provide the complete code for making the connection.Also suggest me some reference  to learn these concepts.

Comment: I don't have examples, but there are plenty out there.  As for the specific example without Azure Storage, this is *how* to do it, but I've never implemented it.  As for references, I highly suggest google.com.

Comment: Thanks Erik ,I have found a tool which do something similar that I want ,but I don't How I get the code for this case  [Azure Service Bus Explorer](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/paolos/2015/03/02/service-bus-explorer-2-6-now-available/)

Answer (score 2):

You will have to use [Custom CheckpointManager for EventProcessorHost (EPH)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-java-get-started-receive-eph#implementing-a-custom-checkpointmanager-for-eventprocessorhost-eph) if you dont want to use default azure checkpoint manager. Mikhailshilkov has a sample SQL checkpointmanager implementaion.[SQLcheckpointManager Sample](https://github.com/mikhailshilkov/mikhailio-samples/blob/master/eventhubs-sqlcheckpoints/SQLCheckpointManager.cs)

Comment: the first link that you provided does not take you to where the text implies. I think it might be a mistake. The custom sample of the Checkpoint manager mentioned in the second link is very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `EventHubConsumerClient.ReadEventsAsync`. To me this is better, because I don't want to use blob storage. But I am getting `Error reading event: EventHubsException(ConsumerDisconnected)` from time to time

Answer (score 0):

Refer docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.azure.messaging.eventhubs?view=azure-java-stable

Code snippet :

```
EventHubConsumerAsyncClient consumer = new EventHubClientBuilder()
         .connectionString(connectionStr,eventhubName)
         .consumerGroup(EventHubClientBuilder.DEFAULT_CONSUMER_GROUP_NAME)
         .buildAsyncConsumerClient();
// Receive data for partition "0"
 consumer.receiveFromPartition("0", EventPosition.latest()).subscribe(event -> {
        System.out.println("Event received : "+event.getData().getBodyAsString());

      });
```